# knockout-kendo widgets with knockout validation not working

Tags: knockout-validation, knockout-kendo

I need to implement knockout validation with knockout-kendo.

I have this html:

```
<textarea class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: description"></textarea>
<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { 
                  data: myOptions, 
                  value:myOptionId,
                  dataTextField: 'MyOptionName', 
                  dataValueField: 'MyOptionId'}"/>
<input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: {value: dueDate}"/>
```

Javascript:

```
...
viewModel: {
    description: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
    dueDate: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
    myOptions: ko.observableArray([]),
    myOptionId: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true })
}
...
    ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(self.viewModel, $ctx[0]);
```

The validation works fine for the description field, bound to the text area; but it doesn't work for the comboBox or the datePicker.

I have checked the documentation, and also [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/h9JKx/) jsFiddle, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that the `<span class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: dueDate"></span>` doesn't get automatically generated for knockout-kendo tags. Just add a tag per knockout-kendo element, ex:

```
<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { 
                  data: myOptions, 
                  value:myOptionId,
                  dataTextField: 'MyOptionName', 
                  dataValueField: 'MyOptionId'}"/>
<span class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: value:myOptionId"></span>
<input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: {value: dueDate}"/>
<span class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: dueDate"></span>
```

Remember to put before your view model:

```
ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
});
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```